# Deserialize byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, deserialization

I have a byte array and I need to de-serialize it to several object types.

The object contain `{float,short,int}`. In Java I would do it with `ObjectInputStream` like this:

```
ObjectInputStream is;
is.readFloat()
is.readShort()
is.readInt()
```

I looking for a way to do it in C#.

Read the first x byte as float the next y byte as short and the next z byte as int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use a [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx):

If you have a byte array that you want to deserialize, you wrap it in a memory stream and then use the `BinaryReader`. Like this:

```
byte[] inputArray;  // somehow you've obtained this
using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(inputArray))
{
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(inputStream))
    {
        float f1 = reader.ReadSingle();
        short s1 = reader.ReadInt16();
        int i1 = reader.ReadInt32();
    }
}
```

You can also do it with the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) class, but you have to maintain state. For example, you can read a `float`, a `short`, and an `int` like this:

```
byte[] inputArray;
int ix = 0;

float f1 = BitConverter.ToSingle(inputArray, ix);
ix += sizeof(float);  // increment to the next value

short s1 = BitConverter.ToInt16(inputArray, ix);
ix += sizeof(short);

int i1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(inputArray, ix);
ix += sizeof(int);
```

Of the two, I'd suggest using the `BinaryReader`, because it's more flexible and easier to work with in most cases. `BitConverter` is handy if you only have a handful of items to deserialize. I suppose it has the potential of being faster, but that wouldn't matter unless your app is *highly* performance sensitive. And if deserializing data is that critical, you'd probably write a custom deserializer.

Comment: To OP: `BinaryReader` only takes a `Stream` object in its constructors, so if all you have is a `byte[]` array you can simply wrap it in a `MemoryStream`: `= new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(byteArray))`

Comment: @Cory: Thanks. I should have mentioned that.